# How to config multi repositories in one Alfresco instance?

Tags: repository, alfresco

How to config multi-Repositories in one Alfresco instance ?

such as in ' `alfresco-global.properties`' , I can config multi-Repositories locations:

```
dir1.root=\\server1\driver1\alf_data

...

dir2.root=\\server1\driver2\alf_data

...

dir3.root=\\server2\driver1\alf_data
```

And I can manage all these Repositories in this Alfresco instance.

Benefit:
1) I can manage them in one Alfresco instance.
2) I can increase my storage capacity anytime to add new Repositories.
3) improve search&index performance as there are many different Storage hard disk.

How to do that?

Also we can track this issue at Alfresco official [forum](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/installation-upgrades-configuration-integration/configuration/how-config-multi-repositories)

Answer (score 1):

You can just add Content Stores to Alfresco, take a look here: http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Content_Store_Selector or here: http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/concepts/store-manage-content.html

So basically, you're adding a new store to Alfresco next to the workSpace/SpacesStore.
By adding an Aspect to a content you can move the content to the other location.

Probably you'll need to do some more stuff, but this will get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Alfresco does not have a multi-repository feature. You always have one repository, but:

- you can add & manage different content Stores as Tahir mentioned.
- you can also use non-file-system content stores like EMC Centera, NetApp Filer...
- you can also use elastic content stores like Caringo CAStor
- you can enable multi tenancy mode
- without extensive programming you'll always have 1 central DB & 1 central search index for now

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with store selector. But I heard its been removed in 4.2 community. Yet to verify it.

Comment: content Stores & tenancy mode are all need Enterprise edition!
how to get it in Community Edition?